# Samsung Galaxy S4 only boots for 5 seconds, then dies

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, boot

Yesterday I was using my phone, and suddenly it shut off. I tried the power button, but it wouldn't turn on again. I then took the battery out, and put it back in. Immediately, the phone vibrated, and displayed the Samsung Galaxy splash screen (this happened without me pressing the power button). After about 5 seconds, it shuts off, and I have to start the process over again. I tried booting in safe mode, and recovery mode, and the same thing happened. Interestingly, If I take the battery out, plug the phone in, then put the battery back in, the phone doesn't automatically start, but it still doesn't boot either. I tried changing the battery, but that didn't seem to make a difference. Initially I thought it might be something wrong with the power key, however, I would expect that if that were the case, it should be constantly restarting, not shutting off and staying off.

What could possibly be causing this? Is this more likely hardware or software, and is there any way to fix it that isn't just replacing it?

Comment: I think you're right about the power key problem. Samsung phones don't restart like that unless you let go of the power key. I've had this problem myself - although the issue disappeared after sixteen hours.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, Ephraim, I just want to confirm that I'm having the exact same problem as you described right now. There was hope at one point, though. I had the phone just lying there with the battery in it, and it randomly booted up without my intervention and worked properly. It last about 2 minutes, then turned black and off, and the same problem is happening again...